# Highlighting new items fetched when clicking "x questions with new activity"

Tags: feature-request, design

I’d like to propose a feature request:

I’d like there to be some kind of highlighting in the questions list of the list entries that where added by the last click of the *“x questions with new activity”* message.

---

**Scenario:**

- I have read through the list of questions on the main page of a SE site, and keep it open in a browser tab.
- There have been some new activity, so it is showing *“x questions with new activity”*.
- I click the message and it updated the list.
- I start reading the new material, skipping some, opening others in tabs, reading through them and going back to the list.
- Then, after a few questions I start to ask myself:

  - *“Was it 10 or 16 questions with new activity last time I clicked the message?”*
  - *“All these titles seem familiar..., which ones are new (activity-wise) and  which ones have I already checked on?”*
  - and even: *“I remember there where 22 questions with new activity on the last update click, but which number question have I scrolled down to now? They aren’t numbered...”*

---

What I’d like is for the new entries to be highlighted until the next click on the “new activity” message. Since, of course, when I click the “new activity” the next time I only want the *new* ones to actually be marked.

The actual design of the highlighting could be anything, however I’d like it to be discrete and not clash with the *favourite tags* highlight.

- For example a thin coloured bar at the left that extends down over all the new entries.
- Or just making the text *“asked/answered/modified xx minutes ago”* in a different colour/weight/background for questions with new activity. (This may be the best way to do it, since these are related concepts.)